# Normal law: is this answer wrong?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I came across this problem (originally from [here](http://www.jybaudot.fr/Probas/exloinormale.html), in french):

> A bottling machine fills bottles of $100$ units of juice. The bottling
> machine is not accurate, and so the actual volume of juice inside a
> bottle follows a normal distribution with standard deviation
> $\sigma=1.5$. The average volume $m$, on the other hand, is
> adjustable. What is the value of $m$, such that $95$% of the bottles
> contain at least $99$ units of juice.

If $X$ denotes the volume inside a bottle, we want to find the value of $m$ such that:
$$
P(X\ge \frac{m-99}{\sigma}) \ge 0.95
$$

Up to here, everything is ok. The author then states that the problem is equivalent to finding $m$ such that:
$$
P(X\le \frac{m-99}{\sigma}) \le 0.95
$$

I cannot manage to prove this equivalence. Is this true ? If not, what would be the correct answer ?

Comment: It should rather be equivalent to find $m$ s.t. $\mathbb P\{X<\frac{m-99}{\sigma }\}=\mathbb P\{X\leq \frac{m-99}{\sigma }\}\leq 0.05$.

Comment: Actually, I believe the error is in the first equation. I think it should be $P(X \ge \frac{99-m}{\sigma}) \ge 0.95$ which is indeed equivalent to $P(X \le \frac{m-99}{\sigma}) \le 0.95$.